# Open VPN: add DNS rule to change server domain to local IP

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, resolve

I have a working setup, where all traffic is redirected via a open VPN tunnel. Only issue I have left is, that I want the domain of the server to be the local IP address. Meaning that when the client resolves the server domain it should return the openVPN IP instead of the public IP.

Idea behind this is, that some services only are accessible through the VPN and not from the public IP.

Can I implement this in the client openVPN config file somehow or overwrite the dns forwarding from the server?

Edit:

As the domain was running on another dns server, I simply activated the DNS Server on the openvpn host and setup the domain with the interal IP. Now everything works as expected!

Comment: Do you have an internal DNS Server in your setup ?

Comment: Ahhh, yes - good Idea!